# Ubuntu 16.10 GUI problems (Unity, KODI, FluxBox, KDE)

Tags: desktop-environments, bug-reporting

I have a laptop running the latest Ubuntu, with regularly installed updates. I have several desktop environments installed alongside Unity, including KODI, FluxBox, and Unity 8 preview. Shortly before updating to 16.10 from 16.04, I installed KDE, and this is where my problems started.

Some desktop elements do not display correctly, I.E. newly launched windows appear behind the launcher instead of beside it. Also, there are two active sets of mouse pointers, and Ubuntu switches between them randomly.

[image: terminal window behind launcher]

Comment: Really common that many desktop environments installed at the same time cause problems. Consider getting rid of any you don't use or you can do without.

Comment: I have tried uninstalling the DEs, even reinstalling unity. Nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve most of my problems by installing CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager). Although many of the default graphical features of Unity were "enabled" in the default system settings app, many had become disabled, and many more are hidden from view (by default).

I installed CCSM and re-enabled Window snapping, Window placement, and desktop wall.

Now I need to figure out how to reset the mouse pointers to use only the the Humanity themed set.